# How can I mock pirates in obfuscated source code?

Tags: android

I am working on a paying app which will have LVL enabled, which means that pirates will probably crack it - even if the app is worthless to them.

Given that I am planning on obfuscating code, is there a 'best practice' for inserting a message in the source code that will not be obfuscated ?

Comment: Surely doing this would just annoy the pirates and cause them to double their efforts. Obfuscation isn't 100% effective...

Comment: Yes... Maybe I should add advertising in the source code too. This would cater for the hacking audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using proguard doesn't obfuscate litteral strings.](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#encrypt)